# uiwebview load request not working ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, app-transport-security

Having seen that `WKWebview` doesn't support post request, I used old `UIWebView` for loading post request, but unfortunately the page itself not loading. In the `webview` delegate the response is 200, but nothing is seen in `webview` and debug console i noticed

```
 WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
```

I have added app transport settings in plist for the url "192...." but still i'm getting the page is not loading in the webview and same logs are in debug.

Comment: What you need to do whether you need to open web-view or something else Can u plz post your query in details with source code also where you're facing the issue then only anyone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify IP addresses in your App Transport Security (ATS) exception **domains** list.  You must use the domain name.  However, if you are trying to disable ATS for local network traffic, you can set the `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` value under App Transport Security in your Info.plist to true, like the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>    
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I'm not entirely convinced this is the issue (your console message doesn't match what I have seen when ATS is blocking traffic).  However, if you put 192.xxx.xxx.xxx in your exception domains list, it will definitely not do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm doing a post request in UIWebView, for a payment navigation but the corresponding page is not rendered, i'm getting response status 200 and content type "text/html" and webview is blank but it is working in android webview

Comment: Can you post your webview code where you make the POST request?  Have you tried it with the `NSAllowsArbitratyLoads` ATS setting to disable ATS altogether?

Comment: What was the solution?  If it was the solution above, please accept the answer so if others come to this with the same problem.  If something else, post it as an answer.